# Como usar "que" x "do que"

Tags: gramática, preposições

Dentro dessa frase:

> Brasil detinha grandes reservas de moedas estrangeiras. Isso foi fruto
>   de mais importações [..] exportações

Nesse situação `[..]` qual é o uso mais correto: "que" ou "do que" ?

Comment: Apenas `que`, eu diria.

Comment: "Mas importações **do que** exportações", ou "mais importações **que** exportações", como já tens na resposta abaixo. Mas logicamente, só com o texto apresentado, é "mais exportações **que/do que** importações": mais importações do que exportações contribui para reduzir as reservas de moeda estrangeira.

Answer (score 1):

As comparações não se fazem com *de que*. Por isso a resposta, é ***do que***. Por exemplo, a gramática de Cunha e Sintra refere os seguintes conectores de comparação: *que*, *do que*, *qual* (depois de *tal*), *quanto* (depois de *tanto*), *como*, *assim como*, *bem como*, *como se*, *que nem*.

Neste caso, apenas *que* também seria possível. Sobre a frequência relativa das várias opções, no CETEMPúblico (texto jornalístico português dos anos 90), temos:

Com nomes:

- `"mais" [pos="N"] "do" "que" [pos="N"]`: 478 ocorrências
- `"mais" [pos="N"] "que" [pos="N"]`: 285 ocorrências
- `"mais" [pos="N"] "de" "que" [pos="N"]`: 1 ocorrência (provavelmente gralha)

Com adjetivos:

- `"mais" [pos="ADJ"] "do" "que" [pos="ADJ"]`: 533 ocorrências
- `"mais" [pos="ADJ"] "que" [pos="ADJ"]`: 347 ocorrências
- `"mais" [pos="ADJ"] "de" "que" [pos="ADJ"]`: 0 ocorrências

Portanto, *do que* e *que* têm frequências semelhantes.

Como uma nota final, em minha opinião a frase não é muito feliz. Eu escreveria: *Isso foi fruto de **ter havido**/**se terem registado** mais importações do que exportações*. Assim a estrutura da frase torna-se evidente mais cedo.

Comment: Eu compreendo lindamente a tua resposta, até porque já vi muitas tuas deste tipo, mas não podias tornar as contagens mais claras para quem esteja menos habituado aquele tipo de notação ( [pos = "ADJ"], etc.)? Talvez com exemplos?